# cannot compute a simple date difference with lubridate

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Using `lubridate` I want to extract the difference in days between two dates, as a pure integer number. However, I cannot seem to manage that:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
current <- Sys.Date()
future <- ymd('2020-03-13')
mday(future - current)
#> Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)): do not know how to convert 'x' to class "POSIXlt"
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: How about `as.numeric(future - current)` - that returns `7`?

Comment: @AllanCameron that's also fine. I thought there could be a way to do it from within `lubridate`, but I'll take whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation on mday(future - current) why this was not working.

mday finds out day in a month which requires just one argument.

```
mday(future)
```